# Integration by parts goes wrong

Tags: calculus

Trying to integrate:

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x \ln x}  ,\  x>0$$

but something went wrong.

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x \ln x}=\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}-\int\frac{\ln x}{-x \ln^2 x} \mathrm dx = 1 + \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x \ln x}$$
which obviously is wrong. Where did I screw up?

Comment: $+C$...${}{}{}$

Comment: Your integration by parts is fine, but as David Mitra said: You need the +C.
In the end your +1 becomes redundant and vanishes in the C,

Comment: How is IBP possible for integrals without bounds? You need $g(x)f(x) \Big|^{a}_{b}$

Answer (score 4):

You don't need intgration by part !

$$\frac{1}{x\ln x}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\ln x}$$
and it's of the form
$$\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$$
with $u(x)=\ln x.$

Therefore $$\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx=\ln(\ln(x))+C.$$

Comment: Neat! Is it not possible to integrate by parts?

Comment: it doesn't look like.

Answer (score 1):

Your work isn't incorrect, but it's not helpful in evaluating the integral.

Your equation is just:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac {\mathrm dx}{x \ln x} = \int \frac {\mathrm dx}{x \ln x} + C$$

There's no point in writing $C + 1$, because any arbitrary constant plus one is still an arbitrary constant.